# accessing association of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with a user model that sets up friend relationships like this

User.rb

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
```

Each user has a `has_many` association with the Recipe.rb model

In my app, I want to post recipes on a user's show page by the friends of that user. i.e. go through the friends association to get the recipes of the friends. Therefore, I do this in the users_controller.rb

```
def show 
  @friend_recipes = []
  @user.friendships.each do |friendship|
    @friend_recipes << User.recipes_by_friends(friendship.friend_id)
  end 
end
```

which calls the class method `recipes_by_friends` on the user model

User.rb

```
scope :recipes_by_friends, lambda { |friend_id|
  joins(:recipes).
  where(recipes: {user_id: friend_id})     
}
```

In the user show page, I try to show each of the recipes. However, in the code below, the recipe local variable is actually an active record relation for the friend, not the recipes for the friend.

/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% @friend_recipes.each do |recipe| %></li> 
  <%= recipe.inspect %>  ## this is the relation for the user, not the recipe 
<% end %>
```

1. How should I change the scope method (or change something else?) in the User model to get the recipes?
2. Is this the best way to loop through friends and add their recipes to an array?

   ```
   @user.friendships.each do |friend|
     @friend_recipes << User.recipes_by_friends(friend.friend_id)
   end
   ```

Comment: For #2, I would use @user.friendships.map{|v| block}. If the block could return nil the append with .compact

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to change the scope method so that it's returning the recipes rather than the friend?

Comment: `recipes_by_friends` is a query so it returns a collection of matches. In your case, I think you are assuming one match? In that case, you could do: `<%= recipe.first.inspect %>`. If there are multiples, you might need an "inner each": `<% recipe.each do |r| %> ...`.

Comment: @mbratch I wanted all recipes by all friends in that scope recipes_by_friends, but it's returning the friends instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can let ActiveRecord do the grunt work for you in this case.

**user.rb**

```
has_many :friend_recipes, :through => :friends, :source => :recipes
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show 
  @friend_recipes = @user.friend_recipes 
end
```

The actual SQL query generated by that would be:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > user = User.first
2.0.0p247 :002 > user.friend_recipes
  Recipe Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" INNER JOIN "friends" ON "recipes"."friend_id" = "friends"."id" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "friends"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
```

Comment: There isn't a model called FriendRecipe, so I don't know if you can do has_many :friend_recipes. However, when I try your code i get a 'stack level too deep' error.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I just made a test application with those associations to make sure they would work (they did). No need to worry about the fact that the model doesn't exist because `has_many` takes as argument only the association name -- which can be anything you want, as long as you provide other options that help Rails figure out where to find the information. In our case, that's done by the `:source` option.